# RLC Q factor measurement

Tags: bandwidth, frequency-measurement, passive-filter

I have a simple parallel RLC circuit (R in series to L and C which are in parallel to each other). I am using a 0.01 micro farad CK05 capacitor a 100k resistor and a 10mH inductor.

I measure a resonance frequency of 17.1kHz which is close to the theoretical resonance frequency of 15.9kHz.

My problem is in the bandwidth. I am measuring a bandwidth of approximately 1.5kHz giving a Q factor of approximately 11.4 while the theoretical value  is bigger by an order of magnitude i.e. 10 times larger (using \$ Q=\omega_0RC \$ for parallel RLC circuit I calculated Q=~100).

I measured the bandwidth by varying the frequency and measuring the frequencies where \$V=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}V_{max} \$ (using the cursors and measurement options on a digital scope).

What may be the reason for this kind of error?

below I added a picture of the components I used, from left to right:
resistor capacitor and inductor. I used an ohm meter and measured the DC resistance of the inductor to be 66 ohm.
[image]

Comment: What is the resistance of the inductor you are using?

Comment: Are you referring to the ESR? I have no knowledge of that and I do not know how to experimentally measure it. But I'm always open to learning new things :)

Comment: No, I mean the DC resistance.  You can measure it with an Ohm meter.

Comment: I'm no longer in the lab so I'll check that tomorrow and update my question. But anyway, how exactly will this affect the bandwidth of the circuit?

Comment: I measured it as suggested and found it to be 66 ohms

Comment: Some people here saw were I was going with this and gave the answer.  I was hoping you will figure out yoursel that Q=Xl/R.  So the Q of your iductor is 16 or less.  You should put this resistance in series with you inductor and recalculate your Q.  The resistance of this inductor will actually be a bit higher because of skin effect.  So do you understand why you Q is not 100 now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Q factor for any tuned LC circuit cannot be higher than the Q factor of the inductor itself and, if the inductor's series resistance is high enough, it will dominate the Q factor of the tuned circuit.

So, given that you have witnessed a Q of 11.9 with an inductive reactance of 1049 Ω at 16.7 kHz, the ESR of the inductor must be about 88 Ω.

Now this may not directly translate to the measured DC resistance because of [skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect), [proximity effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_effect_(electromagnetism)) and possibly core losses but I would expect that the inductor you have chosen is a few tens of ohms in DC resistance.

---

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor), a series RLC tuned circuit has a Q of: -

\$\dfrac{1}{R}\sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}\$ and, if you rearrange the formula when the circuit is at resonance you get: -

Q = \$\dfrac{\omega_0L}{R}\$ and this is the same as the Q factor for an inductor.

What is the relevance of this you might ask? It's relevant because if you throw away the 100 k feed resistor you are left with L and C in series with the AC resistance of the coil; in other words, the best Q you can achieve is defined by the Q of a series tuned circuit driven from a perfect voltage source.

Comment: can you direct me to a proof showing that a tuned circuit's Q factor cannot be higher than the Q factor of the inductor It uses?

Comment: Look up the Q factor for a series tuned RLC circuit because when you remove the 100 kohm driving resistor, in effect this is what you have with the inductor's series resistor. Also, can you confirm what inductor you used?

Comment: I added a picture of the inductor I used and I measured it's DC resistance using an ohm meter. it was a few tens of volts as you predicted, more specifically 66ohms.

Comment: You have your answer then. Did you look up the Q factor for a series RLC? I'll add some more thoughts to my answer...

Comment: I read some about series RLC from a file i found online. I eagerly await your updated answered :)

Comment: I've amended my answer to state the series tuned circuit Q and how it applies to a parallel tuned circuit with coil resistance.

Answer (score 1):

> 10mH chokes in the lab will probably be low Q<<100 due to high DCR >>10 Ohms
>
> In order to make a Q = 100 filter you need an inductor with a higher Q than the filter.

*I could be wrong but I believe the series Rloss transforms into a Norton equiv circuit Rshunt loss according to the Q?*

Try a smaller choke with high Q and bigger cap.

Q=100 is difficult to obtain in small ferrite chokes due to fine wire turns.

Answer (score 1):

Q factor can "only" be  measured by a Q-meter.

Basically, the schematic is the following. Board must be carefully assembled.

**The injection system for good behavior (and measuring real parameters) is the very important specification.**

**One must be also aware that the Q (and L) parameter vary with frequency !**

**So, one must measure Q at the frequency where inductance is used.**

**All parasitics (capacitors ... unless perhaps missing some ...) are presented and can be evaluated for starting to 1pF. They all influence (sometimes greatly) the Q measured.**

Pads are used for adding externally components.

[image]

Here also a example of results (mix stepping Caux -10pF to 10pF and series resistor inductor 1,3,5 Ohm = R4  ) Vertical axis is in dB.

[image]