# Antenna Coupling via Capacitor 4: Calculation of Q of 'by hand'

Tags: rf, antenna, impedance-matching, receiver

Consider following coupling of antenna to a LC-tank via coupling
capacitor C1 and on the right the replacement circuit of
the antenna:

[image]

I have become aware of a serious knowledge gap of mine
with respect the explicit calculation of Q factor of the tuned circuit,
which according to his explanations strongly depends on the coupling capacitor
C2 and becomes low (= tuning circuit poorely selective) if we would remove
the coupling cap from the circuit. That sounds great, but I don't know how to check it mathematacally via explicit calculation showing how precisely Q depends on C2, C1, L1 (and I prefer to forego simulations if possible or to use them as a 'last resort' of choice; here I think the circuit is 'simple' enough to do it by hand, but how?)

So my question is quite simple: How to calculate here explicitely the
Q factor? I know only how to calculate Q of elemetrary parallel and serial
RLC circuits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#RLC_circuits but don't know which
explicit techniques/ strategies are used here in order to determine Q of a bit more complicated
oscillating systems like this one.

Could somebody explain using this example above (*this* seems indeed easy enough to allow an analytical solution but beyond the well known cases of Q for parallel and serial LRC circuits) how one should attack
the calculation of
of Q in such bit more complicated networks like this one.
Are there any 'rules' and standard techniques known like
'divide and conquer' approaches in the sense that to determine of
Q of complicated oscillating system one can calculate it in some way
from Q's of single components analogously like we can do with resistances, voltages, currents via eg Kirchhoff's circuit laws?

Answer (score 1):

**Basically**, the **Q factor** is defined for **"elements"only (inductor)** and was "extended" to **classic "bandpass"** circuits with **"no ripple"** as in **2nd order only "active filters"**.

This was measured by a [Q-meter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/268257/rlc-q-factor-measurement/584083#584083).

One can see in this picture what are the "parasitics" elements measured, ***generally added in parallel***.

[image]

[image]

When one adds an antenna ("equivalent" simple schematic), one adds a new slightly **coupled inductance** (as in this circuit) which changes all the behavior of the primary inductance.

This is now a **"tuned" circuit** and generally, **it haves two peaks**, so the **definition of Q** can't now be applied.

[image]

For "simplicity", here the schematic of an " long wire antenna" only wired with a "tuned transformer" (Q of inductors Lp and Ls are realistic) where coupling coefficient Kc is varied ... and also coupling capacitor Cpc between inductors. When one mix the two (.?.)...

Varying Kc

[image]

Varying Cpc

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may measure or know otherwise the Q-factors of separate coils and capacitors, even simple LC resonant circuits at a certain frequency. There's no general calculation formula how to combine them to a single Q-factor of a complex circuit which contains those parts. That's because the right formula is different for different circuits. You hopefully believe it by thinking a simple series circuit of 2 inductors, say L1=1mH and L2=1uH. Both of them may have the same Q-factor at 1MHz, but the parasitic series resistance of L1 is the dominant one. It does not help at all to double or quadruple the Q-factor of L2.

Q-factor is a historical relic from the era when the selectivity of the radio receivers was based on having low loss resonant circuit bandpass filters. Radio part sellers had a possibility to advertise for ex: Our tuning circuit coils have the highest available Q-factor, 120 or more over the whole LW-band, guaranteed!

The actual meaningful quantity was the achieved filtering frequency response. For narrowband filters the Q-factor of the total filter circuit is closely related to the ratio of the center frequency and the bandwidth, as said in your linked Wikipedia article. The next image is taken from it:

[image]

You can find the frequency response of a complex narrowband (=resonant) filter with a circuit analysis program and calculate its Q-factor if you need that number for something ; maybe in ad of your product.