# Loaded Q factor crystal oscillator

Tags: oscillator, crystal

If I have a crystal oscillator as shown in the image below, the \$Q_0\$ factor can be defined as:

$$Q_0 = \frac{2 pi f_o L_1}{R_1}$$

[image]

If a resistor is added in parallel, similar to what would happen in a Colpitts oscillator, how would the Q factor be reduced?

My first attempt was to find the Q of the series RLC branch,
transform R1 into a parallel resistor

$$ R_p = R_2 \cdot Q^2 $$

find the equivalent resistance between R1 and R2

$$ R_{eq} = R_1||R_2 $$

and then calculate the new Q of entire network as if it were a parallel RLC network:

$$ Q = \frac{R_{eq}}{2\pi\omega_o L_1} $$

But if I plug in values such that the series resonant frequency is on the scale of 10 MHz and R2 is a 20 or 30 kΩ, the Q factor is close to 0 which doesn't make sense.

Comment: The definition used Q0=omega0*L1/R1 is ok for the inductance. To be checked for this network (?).

Comment: The image you show is of a crystal and not a crystal oscillator. Very big difference.

Comment: To make this crystal oscillate, the external *Colpitts* circuit loads it with a net negative resistance. Why do you think it is +ve resistance? You might first find the frequency where oscillation occurs, then calculate crystal Q *at that frequency*.

Comment: Yes, its really a crystal and not crystal oscillator.  The problem is adding a load resistor because in the case of a colpitts oscillator the resistance at the base junction of the transistor would affect the Q factor of the crystal due to loading effects.  For the sake of the problem we can assume the rest of the colpitts would be driving the oscillation at $$ f_p = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{L\frac{C_1C_2}{C_1+C_2}}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method doesn't work because Req isn't R1 anymore, and you'd need to back-calculate the fraction of Req that is R1 again.

The next best thing, I think, would be to transform C2 || Z (taking Z as the general impedance seen by the open wires) into series form, and then add that with R1.  This will have some maximum value (due to the parallel impedance of C2) and so the Q can only be reduced a modest amount, as expected, if the impedance is resistive to capacitive.  (But C2 can be canceled out by inductance, giving apparently full freedom to inner loop resistance.)

Comment: I'm not completely following... Are you suggesting that Z is just (R+XC1+XL1)?  so take Z||C2 to find total impedance?  I've tried finding impedance in this manner and then taking imaginary component divided by real component but if evaluating at the series resonant frequency the result i arrive at doesn't match the expected result.

Comment: No, Z is the impedance of the external circuit applied to the crystal.

Answer (score 1):

NB: **Q** (**Quality factor of an inductor**, dependent of the frequency ...

See also my answer in **this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/268257/rlc-q-factor-measurement)** ...

until resonance) is defined **at only ONE frequency** \$ Q_o = (2*pi*f_o)* L / R \$.
Note also that some formulas using Q are valid unless **Q >= 10**.
Don't misc the use of Q as the value of : **fo / BW** in RLC circuit at resonance.

When the network is "complicated", it can also be defined by \$Q_f = Im (V(f))/Re(V(f))\$.

It can only be "defined" where the impedance is considered to be an "inductance".

As an example, here is how to consider such network ... (loaded in parallel by R2).
One can see that network is an "inductor" only between fo and fp ...

[image]

Comment: "Q is defined at only ONE frequency Qo=(2∗pi∗fo)∗L/R."  Not true. \$Q=1/R\sqrt{L/C}\$

Comment: SORRY. Q is defined only for an inductor serial with a resistor. Your's is not a inductor quality factor. It does not have the same signification. And it is calculated at one frequency point. Your's is also calculated at 1 point frequency.

Comment: In this instance, it's a crystal oscillator so in the case where there is no parallel R, $$Q = \frac{2\pi*f*L}{R}$$ where f is the series resonant frequency.  I had originally tried to use the generic formula $$Q_f = Im(V(f))/Re(V(f))$$ but first I tried using it without the load resistor to verify that I would get a Q that would match the Q factor given by the equation for a crystal.  When plugging in specific values the answer I get is not close to what I would expect.